# copying previous sibling to clipboard

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard, copy-paste, cpu-word

I'm trying to create a copy button that would copy the text of its previous sibling element to clipboard, without any luck. What am I missing?

Thanks!

```js
function copy(elem) {
  const word = elem.previousSibling.innerText;

 word.select();
 wordsetSelectionRange(0, 99999)
 document.execCommand('copy');
 word.remove();

  alert(word + " copied.");
}
```

```html
words:
<div>
 <div>
  dog
 </div><button
  id="it" onclick="copy(this)">copy
 </button>
</div>

<div>
 <div id="word">
  cat
 </div><button
  id="it" onclick="copy(this)">copy
 </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the word *node*, which you can get by just referencing the `previousSibling` (don't take its content). Then you can create a range spanning from the beginning of the node to the beginning of the next, then set the window's selection to just that range, and then you can copy the selection:

```js
function copy(elem) {
  const wordNode = elem.previousSibling;

  const range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(wordNode, 0);
  range.setEnd(elem, 0);
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);

  document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

```html
words:
<div>
  <div>
    dog
  </div><button id="it" onclick="copy(this)">copy
 </button>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="word">
    cat
  </div><button id="it" onclick="copy(this)">copy
 </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks♥