# Use copy to clipboard next to items in list html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

How can I put a button next to each of these "result" items to copy to clipboard?

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <input name="input" placeholder="Shorten a link here..."/>
    <button class="shorten-btn" type="submit">Shorten It!</button>
</form>
<ul class="results">
    <% for (let i=0; i<results.length; i++) { %>
        <li><%= results[i] %></li>
    <% } %>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Use a button like shown in this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61920211/16634738

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `navigator.clipboard.readText()` and `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` as seen in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard ?